# How can i keep running thread awaited for some separate callbacks to return, without message-loop and async void?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

Suppose we have a wpf window with a button named `button1` that handles a void same as this:

```
void Button1_Clicked()
{ 
   // configuring some new work...

   // awating for this work to be completed:
        while (!_WorkIsCompleted)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }

   // prompting user that this works is completed.
}
```

And Then Suppose this UI scenario:

1. User clicks button1 and the void `Button1_Clicked` calls. Therefore
   ui thread is wating for an specific work to be completed.
2. At this moment user Clicks button1 again and we Start a new work (while older work is still operating and is not completed). And we await using message-loop again for this operation to be completed.
3. The first work is completed. But duo to message-loop architecture, user cannot receive its prompt. Because call stack waits for the later work to be completed, then returns.
4. Therefore, user receives prompt of later work at first, then receives prompt of sooner work.

In other words, older calls will await next calls for return. But if we use an `await` keyword within an `async` void we can make the true result as expected. Because of some architectural and code pattern issues i cannot use tasks in my project. and message-loop cannot make a true result for me.

I know when we use `await` keyword to call an `async` void (or function), it tells compiler (probably at compile time) that make some edits on programmer code to supporting await operation.

And it seems that during await, Call Stack is free to make more calls by running thread. With `await` keyword, we are able to keep running thread awaited for a lot of awaited calls at a same time, that each other is not related to each other. (This behavior is what i want now.)

Actually what is happening in compiled code of an `async` void, that makes await possible for multiple calls separately, with non-freezing the running thread? It must be possible for me to make a same thing for my situation. How can i edit or change my code to make a same behavior? Is there a solution in c# for this?

Comment: I don't know what you expect, but that code will always run all the Send's one after other as Send is synchronous: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Maybe you want to use Post?

Comment: In WPF SynchronizationContext object is of type DispatcherSynchronizationContext which is actually a wrapper around Dipatcher and when you use Post and Send methods - it calls BeginInvoke and Invoke methods behind the scenes

Comment: @Gusman That code makes a message-loop and therefore forces dispatcher to process ui events... (although can be more brief). For example suppose user clicked a button that contains this code, while we are awating for a work to be completed, user clicks this button again.

Comment: @Toddams Yes. This is my practical code that i built all my tests with this. I will edit that code now to be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually what is happening in compiled code of an async void, that makes await possible for multiple calls separately, with non-freezing the running thread?

`await` does *not* create a nested message loop. Instead, `await` will *return* (after capturing a "context"). Later, when the awaited object completes, the remainder of that `async` method will be posted to the context - in this case, a WPF UI context. The main message loop then picks up that message and executes the remainder of the `async` method. I have an [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that explains these basic mechanics in more detail.

> How can i edit or change my code to make a same behavior?

`async`/`await` is a compiler-level transform; it can't be replicated just by code, unless you're willing to do all the transformations yourself (which get messy, especially with loops).

So, the easiest way to make your code work like `await` is to... use `await`.

The first step is to replace the boolean `_IsCompleted` with a signal. In this case, the signal should be asynchronously consumable and will only be triggered once, so the appropriate type is `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (for any `T`):

```
private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _CompletedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
```

Instead of setting `_IsCompleted` to `false`, you set the signal:

```
// was: _IsCompleted = false;
_CompletedTcs.SetResult(null);
```

And then you can just `await` the resulting task:

```
// was: while (!_IsCompleted) { ... }
await _CompletedTcs.Task;
```

Comment: Dear @Stephen Tanks for your helpful answer. It is good, although my question is about "without message-loop **and async void**?". In fact, in our project there is many related functional callbacks that many of them used byRef or out parameters. And this part of code is used many times in that functions.

Comment: I want get rid of `async` keyword and using `Task`s. Because changing all the code is very painful work and using tasks for this kind of project makes codes reading more complex (suppose changing all byRef and out parameters...).

Comment: Can i implement what i want by capturing call stack (execution context) and running it again or such about this? If yes then how?

Comment: When we want use `async` methods within a Console Application then we use a thing such as AsyncContext etc. Can i make use of a thing like this to cover the `async`/`await` from caller? If yes how?

Comment: @lifestyle: Trust me: I've written a *lot* of asynchronous code before `async`/`await`, and the code is **much** cleaner with `async` than without; [see here for an example of an async loop "by hand"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160226-00/?p=93092). Call stack is not the same as execution context. Using `AsyncContext` to hide `async` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @lifestyle: If you want to gradually transition your code to `async`, then I have [a few techniques that may help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). But you don't want to have these hacks as part of your permanent design; they should only be used during a transition period.